# Radio Button ripple cuts off

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, radio-button, ripple

[image]

In the above image the Radio Button delivery ripple cuts off when clicking. I tried padding. But padding only applies for text not the button. I can able to get full ripple in the upper and lower sides by setting height to radio button but I'm unable to fix the ripple cuts in left side.

My XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/goBackBtn"
        style="@style/BackArrayStyle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionBarTitle"
        style="@style/ActionBarTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/goBackBtn"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Filter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgReset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image_primary_ripple"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_reset_black" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_menu"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/radioDelivery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delivery" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioPickUp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pick Up" />

</RadioGroup>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radio_group">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRadiusLabel"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:text="Pick Up Radius"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/div_radius"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height=".3dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvRadiusLabel"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <SeekBar
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/seekBarDistance"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/div_radius"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:max="20"
        android:thumb="@drawable/ic_seek_bar_thumb"
        android:maxHeight="15dp"
        android:minHeight="10dp"
        android:progress="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRadius"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/seekBarDistance"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:text="1 Km" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSortBy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlSeekBar"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Sort By"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/div_seek_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height=".3dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvSortBy"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/div_seek_bar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnRating"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_star_half_white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="7dp"
        android:text="     Rating"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnDistance"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_near_me_white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="7dp"
        android:text="     Distance"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<RadioGroup
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/radio_group1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/div_seek_bar"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioRating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rating" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:text="Distance" />

</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnApply"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:text="Apply Filter"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

How to fix this Ripple issue? Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I guess the issue of padding and margin.

Comment: use weight wise distribution for radiogroup and then check

Comment: why **android:layout_marginStart="30dp"** to radioPickUp

Comment: I tried weight also. Not working

Comment: @RonakThakkar I tried changing padding and margin. Not working.

Comment: @NileshRathod to make more space between two buttons. Checked without that. Not working

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs **android:layout_margin="40dp"** may be check it once

Comment: @NileshRathod tried that. Not working

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs your code is working fine on my device .... no effect is cutting.

Comment: @Umair I don't know what's wrong with my project. Any other reasons for a cause of this issue?

Comment: I made some changes in your code too let me upload it and then you can check.

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs I have updated the answer. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem and fixed it. My team turned off hardware acceleration to fix another issue in the project.

I removed `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in the manifest. Now it's working fine.

Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 2):

Here I made some changes in your code and it's working fine on my devices. Check it if it works for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Primary">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/goBackBtn"
        style="@style/BackArrayStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionBarTitle"
        style="@style/ActionBarTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/goBackBtn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/goBackBtn"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Filter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgReset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image_primary_ripple"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_reset_black" />


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioDelivery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Delivery" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioPickUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:text="Pick Up" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radio_group">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRadiusLabel"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"

            android:text="Pick Up Radius"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/div_radius"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height=".3dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvRadiusLabel"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBarDistance"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/div_radius"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:max="20"
            android:thumb="@drawable/ic_seek_bar_thumb"
            android:maxHeight="15dp"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:progress="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRadius"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/seekBarDistance"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:text="1 Km" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSortBy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlSeekBar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Sort By"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/div_seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height=".3dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvSortBy"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/div_seek_bar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnRating"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_star_half_white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_star_half_white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingStart="7dp"
            android:text="     Rating"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnDistance"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_near_me_white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_near_me_white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingEnd="7dp"
            android:paddingStart="7dp"
            android:text="     Distance"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/div_seek_bar"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioRating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rating" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioDistance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:text="Distance" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnApply"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/primary_text"
        android:text="Apply Filter"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help Umair.  I tried the code. It still cuts the ripple. I think it's not the problem of the layout. Mine and your layout perfectly working on new project which I have created for testing. I'm trying to find out the issue in the project.

Comment: Ok. I think then you have to check your project to find the problem :). Did you checked your styles too ? maybe they are the problem ?

Comment: Yeah. I'll update the solution once I found that. Thanks for the help Umair

Comment: No problem. But you should upload the solution this issue is also looking wired to me ;) . Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Found the issue Umair. It's a problem of disabling hardware acceleration. I have posted the answer.

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs great to hear that. Android never seems to amaze :P